# How come Hulk appeared at this point in the Infinity War trailer?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war

In the below *Avengers: Infinity War* trailer, we see Hulk running with Cap & co. in Wakanda (about 1 minute 59 seconds in).

However, in the movie itself, we

> never see Hulk after Banner lands on Earth early in the movie. In the Battle of Wakanda, Banner wears the Hulkbuster suit the whole time, and never transforms into the Hulk.

Obviously, many things can change between a trailer’s release and the actual movie (see, for example, [Rogue One](https://www.forbes.com/sites/insertcoin/2016/12/21/rogue-ones-original-ending-explains-where-all-those-deleted-trailer-scenes-went/#6dd91c076b8c)), especially things that are mostly made of special effects. But are there any comments from the filmmakers discussing details of how, and perhaps why, this changed between that trailer and the movie?

Comment: Related reading from sister site: [Why was this scene from the trailer not in the film?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/4575/why-was-this-scene-from-the-trailer-not-in-the-film)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While he doesn't reference the Hulk specifically, director Joe Russo, in an interview mentions that misdirecting the audience was a part of Marvel's marketing plans all along. [Here](http://variety.com/2018/film/news/avengers-infinity-ending-1202789363/)'s the interview. And here's the relevant excerpt:

> [Russo said] that misdirection was employed in the marketing of the film to keep the brand’s very loyal and savvy audience from sniffing out what he and his brother were up to. Trailers, for instance, seemed to indicate that mainstays like Captain America and Iron Man might exit stage left, but along with the other members of the original Avengers team (Thor, Bruce Banner/Hulk, and Natasha Romanoff/Black Widow), they live to fight another day.

Comment: They did other things, too, like putting art on toy boxes showing Hulk busting out of Hulk Buster armor.

Comment: They used a similar idea with the Thor: Ragnarok trailer. In the trailers, Thor and Hulk are mid-air with Thor about to give a major upper cut. In the movie, that same scene happened, but Thor was bathed in lightning. Had he been shown with lightning in the trailer, it would have knocked out part of the surprise.

Comment: Yeah, it was all just a red herring to help through off potential leaks and prevent spoilers from hitting the advert circuit.